# Editing content redirects to apache test page?

Tags: nodes

Everything in the site works except for when saving it redirects to an apache test page.  Any ajax request returns an error and the apache test page as debug text?  Any idea?  php 5.3 all requirements met.

*Clarification*
For example:
When editing content and clicking save I am taken to an apache test page.
The url display in the browser is site.com?q=node/1/edit&destination=admin/content
If I refresh the page and send the postdata again I get the apache start page.
If I load that page (like put the cursor in the URL bar and hit enter) it goes to the content edit screen but nothing is saved.

All forms that submit post data it seems do not work.  I dont have this problem anywhere else on the server.

Comment: This is a very localized question and you have also given little-no information.  What error has been returned?

Comment: Nothing shows up in the apache log. No error from drupal.  It just redirects to the apache test page.  Not trying to use clean urls.  Fresh install of 7.7.

Comment: Please give specific URLs. "The apache test page" could be reached by any number of URLs. Please give a specific recipe that creates this problem. Instead of saying "any ajax request returns an error and the apache test page as debug text" say *which* ajax request. Instead of saying "except for when saving" say "When saving page ..."

Comment: added a little bit more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with mod_security.  Disabling it fixes the problem...but is not advised.